# R function that sums up partial words?

Tags: r

**I'm trying to sum up the words 'Moderna' in R and make a count.**
The problem is that the original excel file has the value Moderna mixed with other vaccines. [As you can see, my original R file has words with 'Moderna' in them mixed with 'Oxford/Astrazeneca'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9otXT.png)

This is my attempt trying to sum the words 'Moderna' in the **Code is Below**.

**Code is below:**

```
Number_Of_Countries_Using_Moderna <- Number_of_Vaccines_used %>%
  group_by(vaccines) %>%
  summarize(Moderna_Countries=sum(n))
```

I would group_by vaccines, to get Moderna, then attempt to sum the amount of Moderna (making a new column in the process). The problem is that using 'group_by(vaccines) function' wouldn't be correct.

Do you guys have any suggestions? Thank you for your time :)

Problem was solved with either of the two solutions below, thank you.

Comment: Please don't use pictures or even links to pictures to post data and code. Please make a reproducible example for great good: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to get the sum of `n` whenever Moderna is mentionned in the column `vaccines`? If that's the case, here is a solution below. You need to "filter", not "group_by":

```
Number_of_Vaccines_used %>%
  filter(grepl("Moderna", vaccines)) %>%
  summarize(Moderna_Countries = sum(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask for: If you are looking for a complete list of vaccines and their counts, you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Number_of_Vaccines_used %>%
  mutate(vaccines = strsplit(vaccines, ", ")) %>% 
  unnest(vaccines) %>% 
  group_by(vaccines) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n))
```

This results in something like

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   vaccines               n
   <chr>              <int>
 1 Covaxin                1
 2 EpiVacCorona           1
 3 Johnson&Johnson        2
 4 Moderna               35
 5 Oxford/AstraZeneca   105
 6 Pfizer/BioNTech       82
 7 Sinopharm/Beijing     24
 8 Sinopharm/Wuhan        2
 9 Sinovac               18
10 Sputnik V             20
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(vaccines = c("Covaxin, Oxford/AstraZeneca", "EpiVacCorona, Sputnik V", "Johnson&Johnson", "Johnson&Johnson, Moderna, Pfizer/BioNTech", "Moderna", "Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca"), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This is definitely my intention!
Hmm, not all of the vaccines character values added up (using the R code you wrote without changes)
For example, the 'Moderna' in the question only added up to 6 rather than 35 (my picture in the question adds up to 34 at least)
I do appreciate the help and the idea. Do you have any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: That depends on the actual data. You could share it with `dput(YourData)` or `dput(head(YourData, 30))`.

Comment: > dput(head(Number_of_Vaccines_used))
structure(list(vaccines = c("Covaxin, Oxford/AstraZeneca", "EpiVacCorona, Sputnik V", 
"Johnson&Johnson", "Johnson&Johnson, Moderna, Pfizer/BioNTech", 
"Moderna", "Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca"), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: apologize I can't add more in a single comment.
Do you require more information?

Comment: I added my output from your data. It looks okay for me?

Comment: Maybe my intentions are understood incorrectly.
I'm trying to tally all the moderna, oxford/astrazeneca, etc.
The code Rosalie mentions solves my original questions, which tallies moderna n values to 35, but I would have to do it separately for each vaccine which is redundant.

using your code, it doesn't seem to add everything. It adds some of the vaccines and splitting them. I also ended up with a similar output as you described in the answer.
It's okay if it's not possible, it would just be convenient. Thank you for your time too!
I did add the whole dput in the original question btw.